# Prevent application hanging while getting webpage

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code in my swing application:

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

But downloading the webpage by using the openStream method makes the swing application hang until the webpage is fully downloaded. How do I prevent this/what are the alternatives, so I can show a loading image until the webpage is fully downloaded?

Comment: Do it in a new Thread so the GUI won't freeze and you can update it to show a loading image

Comment: Consider using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), this is exactly meant for such things.

Comment: @nIcE cOw - 
Thx! Will check it out..

Comment: @Alex : You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load in a separate thread:

```java
InputStream is = null;

Thread worker = new Thread() {
    // show "loading..."
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            is = url.openStream();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // show "done" or remove "loading..."
            }
        });
    }
};
worker.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple threads, which wait for each other.